# Extrinsic semiconductor $$-dependence

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, semiconductor-physics

I have the following in my notes:

> [image: Blockquote]

I dont understand the statement 'simple model fails'

Is the graph shown supposed to be theoretical model or is that the experimental data.

This are equation derived before the graph:

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of "simple model fails" can be deduced from the preceding line: "Even dopants need thermal activation", meaning that even the thermal activation—ionization—of the dopant must be taken into account at a sufficiently low temperature.

"Simple model" refers to the horizontal section of the blue line: a temperature-independent concentration of charge carriers supplied by the dopant. Here, we can assume that every dopant is already ionized, so temperature changes don't affect the carrier concentration.

Dopants are generally chosen for their easy thermal activation. At low temperatures, however, this strategy fails.  In this case, we see the decreasing, dotted section of the blue line because neither the bulk material nor the dopant impurity is readily providing mobile charge carriers.  This progressive decrease is sometimes referred to as [dopant (or carrier) freezeout](https://hep.ph.liv.ac.uk/%7Egcasse/Phys389/PHYS389-lecture4.pdf).

> Is the graph shown supposed to be theoretical model or is that the experimental data

You haven't provided a source, so it's difficult to tell. Take it an idealization of the actual trends (i.e., broadly consistent with experiment, but without experimental error). The link above has a similar idealized graph, also unfortunately unsourced:

[image]

Comment: I have added the equations that was derived in the notes, before the plotting of the graph.  Am i correct in assuming that the equation above only gives the non-dotted line. And according to actual experiment, there should be a 'freezeout range'. Thus the model (the equations given) fail because it doesn't disaply a 'freezeout range'

Comment: That equation given for $n_c$ has a temperature dependence, so it can't correspond to the solid horizontal line. It describes thermal ionization of a host **or** impurity atom (given the context, it's probably the host atom, describing the so-called intrinsic region), corresponding to **one** of the sloped lines (solid or dashed) on the graph.

Comment: One problem with this material as presented is that the slide bullet point is too vague in referring to a "simple model." The model being referred to is one where the charge carriers from the host and impurity are added ($n_c$ from the host plus a fixed $N_D$ from the dopant). The equations listed don't capture this addition. That model in turn doesn't capture the very-low-temperature complete freezeout.

Comment: The figure and model are given in page 213: https://docdro.id/kO30Uyw.

Comment: The equations you give (from 4:20, Kittel p209) precede any discussion of doping in the slides; thus, they indeed describe the intrinsic regime. The model being referred to is stated on 4:26 (p211), where the intrinsic and extrinsic carriers are added, and one or the other is assumed to dominate. Then, 4:27 (p215) refers to that model. Has your original question been answered?

Comment: ok i understand. The simple model fails as the model doesn't capture the very-low-temperature complete freezeout